Failover oracle configuration in Spring boot project
I am using oracle database for my spring boot project, I have two database on server A and B, the A server has the primary database while the other is the standby database. The database on server A and B has different service name. How to config the database in the project like this, but use different service names on different hosts
 SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = A)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = B)(PORT = 1521))(FAILOVER = yes)(LOAD_BALANCE = yes))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = oraDb))))


In a @Configuration class, define your own
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource()

where you will decide which data source to access according to the circumstances: parameter, property, environment variable, ... or just failover to standby one when connection to primary fails.

I already thought this solution, Are there any ways that I can config in the yml file and I do not have to change my code?
